# SQL Query to Py(spark)

Tags: sql, apache-spark, pyspark, count, aggregation

I have the following SQL query which I want to convert to pyspark. I want to take two columns pp and gender and do the following in pyspark

```
%sql             
SELECT pp
,       SUM(CASE WHEN Gender = 'M'
               THEN 1.0 ELSE 0.0 END) /
        COUNT(1) AS gender_score
,       count(1) AS total
FROM df 
WHERE gender in ('M', 'F')
GROUP BY pp
HAVING count(1) > 100
```

I tried this

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import expr 
test_df = df.withColumn("gender_score", expr("CASE WHEN Gender == 'M' THEN  1 WHEN Gender == 'F' THEN  0 ELSE 'other' END AS male_score"))
```

But I don't know how I can select just 2 columns in pyspark and replicate the above-mentioned SQL query to pyspark

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

If you want a python solution:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

def df_func(df, grp):
    test_df = df.filter( 
        F.col('gender').isin(['M','F'])
        ).groupBy(grp).agg(
            F.mean(
                F.when(F.col('Gender') == F.lit('M'), 1.0).otherwise(0.0)
            ).alias('gender_score'),
            F.count(F.lit(1)).alias('total')
        ).filter('total > 100')
    return test_df

result = df_func(df, 'pp')
```

You can use Spark SQL by creating a temp view of your dataframe:

```
df.createOrReplaceTempView('df')
query = """
SELECT pp
,       SUM(CASE WHEN Gender = 'M'
               THEN 1.0 ELSE 0.0 END) /
        COUNT(1) AS gender_score
,       count(1) AS total
FROM df 
WHERE gender in ('M', 'F')
GROUP BY pp
HAVING count(1) > 100
"""
test_df = spark.sql(query)
```

Comment: thanks v much. but the idea is to have it py(spark) not spark SQL

Comment: @JamesTaylor see edited answer with pyspark solution.

Comment: sorry if it's too much. can this be converted to a function that I can use? the only parameter which will change is groupBy :)

Comment: i added this ```/count(lit(1)).alias('gender_score') ``` but the i get strange column name

Comment: @JamesTaylor use F.mean if you want to calculate average, see edited answer.

Answer (score 0):

The groupBy agg() functions takes multiple expressions. So you can do a sum/count expression.

```
val df = spark.sql(""" with t1(
select 10 pp, 'M' gender union all
select 10 pp, 'F' gender union all
select 10 pp, 'M' gender union all
select 40 pp, 'F' gender 
) select * from t1
""")

df.show(false)

+---+------+
|pp |gender|
+---+------+
|10 |M     |
|10 |F     |
|10 |M     |
|40 |F     |
+---+------+

df.groupBy("pp").agg (
    (sum(expr("CASE WHEN Gender = 'M' THEN  1 ELSE 0 END "))/count(lit(1)) ).alias("gender_score"),
    count(lit(1)).alias("total")
).show(false)

+---+------------------+-----+
|pp |gender_score      |total|
+---+------------------+-----+
|40 |0.0               |1    |
|10 |0.6666666666666666|3    |
+---+------------------+-----+
```

After that you can implement "having" using another filter.